# When I change code, save and it, and test it on my browser, it still runs the old code, why?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, osx-lion, textmate

I am using html5 and javascript on Mac OSX Lion. My text editor is text mate, though it is out of date. So I tried saving it in text editor. Ran it and it still executed old code that I had deleted and saved. Does someone have an idea what the error might be? Thanks.

--Udate-- Figured it out: Thanks to everyone for the speedy answer! Turns out I had to close the browser after emptying the cache for it to take affect. I did a few closing and opening tests, and essentially if I just refresh the page, it accomplishes the same as emptying the cache. What I was doing was just closing after I clicked my html and saw what it did, then reopen it. But yea, emptying the cache worked. Thanks again!

Comment: Disable cache of your browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your browser is cacheing the old files. Turn off the cache in your browser!

Comment: To both EdHeal and @KMan It is the first thing I did!!! I did not turn it off, but I did clear it, ran it again, and same issue. --Update-- Ok so I did not know that when you do empty the cache you must first exit the browser then try it again.

Answer (score 2):

delete browser cache using ctrl+shift+delete key
and then refresh you page

Answer (score 1):

It probably has to do with that the browser caches your page. Make sure that the cache is cleared when deploying new content.

How to quickly clear cache is different in each browser so google how you easy can invalidate the cache in your browser of choice.

Answer (score 1):

http://itdc.lbcc.edu/cps/engines/clearcache/index.html Use this to clear your cache.

Answer (score 0):

Do ctrl-F5 to fetch an uncached version of your page.